# Covnerting api logs class objects of list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the response using API in Data Dog tool. When I tried to get the data, it's list of dictionary but I am unable to apply any dictionary operations.
data:

```
data = [{'host': 'abc, 'service': 'qwe', 'status':'fail', 'message': 'failure'},
{'host': 'def', 'service': 'qwe', 'status':'fail', 'message': 'failure'}]
```

Type of the elements of dictionary

```
for i in data:
    print(type(i))
```

```
<class 'datadog_api_client.v2.model.log_attributes.LogAttributes'>
<class 'datadog_api_client.v2.model.log_attributes.LogAttributes'>
```

When I tried the code

```
for sub in attrib:
    for k in sub.keys():
         if k == 'message':
            print(sub[k])
```

```
 raise ApiAttributeError(
datadog_api_client.exceptions.ApiAttributeError: LogAttributes has no attribute 'keys' at ['['received_data', 'data', 0, 'attributes']']['keys']'
```

Expected Output:

```
failure
failure
```

Comment: Probably the `__repr__` method is designed to be output as a dictionary

Comment: @DaniMesejo it converted to string not a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [i.__dict__['_data_store'] for i in data]
for sub in attrib:
for k in sub.keys():
     if k == 'message':
        print(sub[k])
```

First changes the class object into dict object of list so that you can iterate.
Output:

```
failure
failure
```